# Can I Make NOT Using OR and AND?

Tags: logic

I know i can invert X using NOT.
NOT x = x'

But, can i invert X just with OR & AND ?

Example

Given this function
F = W'.Y.Z' + V.W'.Z'

Can i make a circuit just with OR & AND ?

Thanks

Comment: No: unlike the `{AND, NOT}` set of operations, the `{AND, OR}` set is not [*functionally complete*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because has nothing to do with programming and is about electronic circuits.

Comment: @Rob The same concepts could be applied to bitwise operations. (Though the OP did use the word circuits)

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans Yes, he did, and it should be closed for that reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to make NOT out of AND and OR.  The first obvious reason is that NOT takes only one argument, while both AND and OR take two.  Even if you feed the same variable twice to the AND/OR gates, they will not invert its value

OTOH, you can define AND in terms of OR+NOT and you can define OR in terms of AND+NOT

```
x AND y = NOT((NOT x) OR (NOT y))
x OR y = NOT((NOT x) AND (NOT y))
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't get **NOT** with just combinations of **ANDs** and **ORs**.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get NOT from OR and AND. Proof:

With a 0 input, OR and AND will both be 0. There will be no 1 anywhere in the system. With a 1 input, OR and AND will both be 1. There will be no 0 anywhere.

This is why NAND and NOR chips are popular for small/hobby electronics, since they can make any other logic combination.